# Dimension of the linear system of a divisor and topological calculation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Before exposing my question, I'd like to specify that I'm *not* a geometer. So, please, be explicit as much as possible (and excuse me for this probable dumb question).

Given a divisor $D$ on a complexe projective curve $X$, there is a nice way to build a line bundle, $[D]$, which first Chern class is almost $D$ : it's just the Poincaré dual of $D$ when understood as homology class.

For example, if I take the canonical bundle $K_X$ of $X$, then $$K_X = c_1(T^*X) = -c_1(X).$$

And now there is two ways to compute $l(K_X)$, the dimension of the linear system of $K_X$. On one hand, we can do some explicit computation (it's classical algebraic geometry).
On the other hand, if I admit that $l(K_X)$ is the genus of $X$, $g(X)$, then since :
$$\langle c_1(X),[X]\rangle = \chi(X) = 2-2g(X)$$
we get
$$ l(K_X) = \frac {\langle K_X,[X]\rangle}2 - 1.$$

My questions are the following :

- Is there such a way to compute $l(D)$ for a general divisor $D$, i.e. in terms of the topology of the line bundle associated ? (Please don't just tell me that it is the dimension of $H^0(X,\mathcal O(D))$. I want something more computable.)
- If yes, is the formula : $$l(D) = \frac{\langle D,[X]\rangle}2 - 1$$
  reasonable ?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Isn't $\langle D, [X] \rangle$ the same as ${\rm deg \ } D$, the degree of the divisor $D$? Then as far as I'm aware, the best result we have is Riemann-Roch, which in your notation says that $l(D) - l(K - D) = l(O) - l(K) + {\rm deg \ } D$. In the case $D = K$, this reduces to $l(K) = \frac 1 2 {\rm deg \ } K$ (without the $-1$).

Comment: Generally, no. If $D = deg(D)\cdot x$ with $x$ the restriction of the cohomological class $g\in H^2(P^2;\mathbf Z)$ to $X$ then $\langle x, [X]\rangle$ is in fact the degree of $X$ as a curve. So you should get something like $deg(D) \times deg(X)$. I know my formula is probably wrong, but if some is true then we should be able to get back to this one in the special case $D=K_X$

Comment: I'm afraid I'm terrible confused now. Sorry! (i) Why are we considering $\mathbb P^2$? (perhaps you're talking about plane curves only?) (ii) What is the class $g$ in $H^2(\mathbb P^2)$? (perhaps it's the hyperplane class?) (iii) Why is $D$ defined as ${\rm deg \ }(D) . x$? (This is something in $H^2(X)$, but I would expect $D$ to be in $H^0(X)$ - in fact, I would have thought that $D$ would simply be defined as ${\rm deg \ }(D) \in H^0(X)$. Sorry for all these questions!

Comment: Ok let's talk only about plane curves. If $X$ is given by a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, then $K=(d-3)L$ where $L$ is the hyperplane class. Now there is a construction that associate a divisor $D$ to a line bundle, say $[D]$. When you're a given $[D]$ then the first Chern class $c_1[D]$ is the Poincaré dual of $D$. That's how I identify $D$ to a cohomological class. And in fact, $L$ goes to $x:=g|_X$ with $g$ the generator of the cohomology of $P^2$. Returning to $K=(d-3)x$ the computation $\langle x,[X]\rangle = d$ gives $K[X] = d^2-3d$ just as $-\chi(X)= -c_1[X]$.

Comment: Oops, you're right, $[D]$ is in $H^2(X)$, not $H^0(X)$ - it's the Poincare dual of the points. Now I'll read the rest of your comment...

Comment: Okay, I agree that $ - \chi (X) = \langle K, [X] \rangle = d^2 - 3d$. (And since $\chi(X) = 2 - 2g$, this is a statement of the degree-genus formula for plane curves.) But nonetheless it's not true that $\rm{deg \ }(K) = d-3$! The degree of $K$ should be $\rm{deg \ } (K) = \langle K, [X] \rangle = d^2 - 3d = 2g  - 2$.

Comment: Oh so maybe I'm just wrong with the degrees of divisors. What's your definition for the degree of a divisor ? Why isn't it just the integer $n$ such as $D=nL$ ?

Comment: My definition for the degree of the divisor is simply the number of points in the divisor. In other words, I think of the divisor as an element of $H_0(X, \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z$. Now if $c_1(D)$ is the Poincare dual (in $X$) of the divisor $D$, which lives in $H^2(X, \mathbb Z)$, then my definition of the degree of $D$ coincides with the intersection pairing of $c_1(D)$ with the fundamental class $[X]$ of $X$, i.e. $\rm{deg}(D) = \langle c_1(D), [X] \rangle$.

Comment: In this case, this is great. Because with my hoped-formula, we can compute $l(D) - l(K-D)$ and I think we get precisely $deg(D) -g+1$. Isn't it marvelous ? :D

Comment: But unfortunately, the formula $l(D) = \frac 1 2 \langle c_1(D), [X] \rangle$ simply isn't true! :( For example, if $D$ has odd degree, then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: However, Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch gives $l(D) - l(K-D) = \langle c_1(D) - \tfrac 1 2 c_1(K) , [X]\rangle = \rm{deg}(D) - \frac 1 2 \rm{deg}(K) = \rm{deg}(D) - g + 1$.